# Create 5 DIV with 1 DIV in the center

Tags: css, html

I want to create DIV like the picture below. 1 Div on the center and 4 div around the center div. Could anybody help??I've tried but I couldn't do it.

[image: http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-d2cKXwWh8Ao/TnyqPrbV5UI/AAAAAAAAAEk/ITl5MniwS30/s144/Untitled-1.jpg]

```
.mid{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:100px;
    background-color:black;
}

.navtop {
    width:700px;
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;

}

.navbottom {
    width:700px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navleft {
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}

.navright {
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

The content will be static. I have a problem with right and bottom div.

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried? You'll get better traction on your question that way. It could also be useful to you, and others, to compare and contrast the attempt vs. the solution.

Comment: any restrictions ? Only with CSS/tables are OK, targetted browsers ...

Comment: If you want to provide a working example of your problems you can use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: do the divs have a static size (width and height) or do they dynamically change with content?

Comment: that was kinda fun to do. i upvoted it. http://jsfiddle.net/tBGLf/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/z2qQG/2/

```
`<style>
#container{width:500px;height:500px;}
#div1{width:300px;height:100px;margin:auto;background:#000;color:#fff;}
#div2{width:100px;height:300px;float:left;background:#000;color:#fff;}
#div3{width:300px;height:100px;margin:auto;background:#000;color:#fff;}
#div4{width:100px;height:300px;float:left;background:#000;color:#fff;}
#div5{width:300px;height:300px;float:left;background:#fff;}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
  <div id="div4">DIV 4</div>
  <div id="div5">DIV 5</div>
  <div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV 3</div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    #div1 { height: 100px; width: 300px; margin-left: 100px; background: orange; }
    #div4 { height: 300px; width: 100px; float: left; background: red; }
    #div5 { height: 300px; width: 300px; float: left; background: blue; }
    #div2 { height: 300px; width: 100px; float: left; background: lime; }
    #div3 { height: 100px; width: 300px; margin-left: 100px; clear: both; background: aqua; }
</style>

<div id="div1">DIV1</div>
<div id="div4">DIV4</div>
<div id="div5">DIV5</div>
<div id="div2">DIV2</div>
<div id="div3">DIV3</div>
```

This would be the most obvious way.  There are several other ways.

Comment: this causes problems on resize :( (neat idea though)

Answer (score 1):

CSS-wise I would probably `position: relative;` DIV 5 and `position: absolute;` the rest, then moving them out with the top, bottom, left and right properties.

```
#wrap {margin: 100px; width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute; background: black;}
.side {position: absolute; background: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
.side.top {height: 100px; top: -100px;} 
.side.bottom {height: 100px; bottom: -100px;}
.side.left {width: 100px; left: -100px;}
.side.right {width: 100px; right: -100px;}

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="side top"></div>
    <div class="side bottom"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
</div>
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rpuK5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Yup. Fairly simple :)

http://jsfiddle.net/x5FrV/1

```
.wrap
{
    position:relative;
    ...
}

.border
{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    ...
}

.top
{
    bottom:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.right
{
    left:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.bottom
{
    top:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.left
{
    right:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top border">1</div>
    <div class="right border">2</div>
    <div class="bottom border">3</div>
    <div class="left border">4</div>

    <div class="content">
        go team sea slug!
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways, so it really depends more on "why" than "how", but if a client said this to me, my first stab would look something like this:

```
<div id="div5">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
    Content
</div>
```

with css like:

```
#div5 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 3em;
    background-color: red;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}

#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4 { position: absolute; background-color: black; color: white; }
#div1, #div3 { width: 100%; height: 2em; }
#div1 { top: -2em; }
#div3 { bottom: -2em; }
#div2, #div4 { height: 100%; width: 2em; }
#div2 { right: -2em; }
#div4 { left: -2em; }
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2rnU/2/)**